# How can we add HTML with <blockquote> tags in UITextView

Tags: uitextview, nsattributedstring, html-rendering

I've got some simple HTML with a blockquote tag I would like to show in a UItextView (which is inside UITableViewCell, so I don't think using UIWebView is the solution to my problem).

I decided to convert it to NSAttributedString and all worked fine, but what I received is quoted text looking exactly the same as text not being cited (no indentation, no block mark).

I would like to ask if there is any way you can achieve something similar to modern quote mentioned here?

Answer (score 2):

`UITextView` does not indent text delimited by `<blockquote>`.
Neither are CSS styles `margin`, `padding` or `text-indent` respected.

Before you convert to `NSAttributtedString` consider parsing `<blockquote>` content to insert a series of `&nbsp;` to indent the text if this a suitable (aka hack) for your data.

`UITextView` does respect some CSS styles. E.g., `font-style`, `font-size`, `text-align`.